# What is the space complexity of this recursive Insertion Sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, space-complexity

```
void recursiveInsertionSort(vector<int> &arr, int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return;
    recursiveInsertionSort(arr, n - 1);
    int val = arr[n - 1], j = n - 2;
    for (j = n - 2; j >= 0 && arr[j] > val; --j)
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    arr[j + 1] = val;
}
```

I thought the space complexity is constant (O(1)),
because I am passing the array by reference.

But I was told it is actually O(n). Why is that ?

Comment: you mention what "everyone" tells you, could you please state what do you yourself think, and what leads you to think that ?

Comment: @LeGEC I am thinking constant space because I am passing array as reference to the function which is just alias of the original array, and in each function call it's just passed as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is consuming O(N) linear space complexity because in each recursive call you are O(1) space, and the function call is made N times as the size of the array, so the values are occupying O(1) * N spaces, which leads to the overall O(N) space complexity of the algorithm.

```
O(1) * N = O(N)
```

Answer (score 6):

The data vector is still occupying space somewhere, even if your function gets it by reference.

But even if you do not want to consider this space, your code still requires O(n) space.

This is because you'll have **O(n) recursive calls**, each occupying (in your case) **O(1)** space on the call stack (for storing the call context - arguments etc.). All this space will be needed when you'll be in the innermost recursive call.

Altogether it is **O(n) space**.

---

**Note:**
`val` will actually have only 1 instance alive at any given time in this case, because it is allocated after the recursive call.
But even if it was defined and used before the call, it would still be O(1) space per call, and the final result would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering, now cleared it's O(N) because each function has it's own val.

Comment: Does not change the result, but technically for the local variables there never exist more than one instance at the same time.

Comment: @robega in this case you'll have only 1 instance of `val` alive at any given time. But you still need the recursive call context (arguments etc) for O(n) recursive calls in the innermost call.

Comment: BTW - You can observe it easily by putting a breakpoint in the innermost call (at the `return` statement). Your IDE can show you the whole call stack and you can see there are O(n) entries there.

Answer (score 1):

O(n) here means that the algorithm uses space in the order of the input data size. Which is exactly what you say: It uses one time the size of the input data. (not counting the stack space used, though)

Even if you took a sinle copy of the array, it would still be O(n), since O(2*n) ~ O(n). If you passed the array *by value*, then the space usage would rise, probably to O(n^2).